# How to apply different GROUP BY to each aggregate functions in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple question, but I was not able to find the answer in documentation or google. I have one table with information about customers and another one with information about orders. Each customer has multiple orders. What I need is to create 3 columns: one with customer ID, one with number of orders for this customer and one with the overall number of orders. Example:

Customers table

```
CustomerID  | PhoneNumber 
____________|____________
   AAA      |   1-222-2
   BBB      |   1-333-3
```

Orders table

```
CustomerID  | OrderID
____________|____________
    AAA     |  1
    AAA     |  2
    BBB     |  3
    BBB     |  4
    BBB     |  5
```

Expected result:

```
Customer ID  | Number of orders  | Total number of orders
_____________|___________________|_______________________
    AAA      |       2           |          5
    BBB      |       3           |          5
```

When I use COUNT(OrderID) I get total number of orders, when I use COUNT with GROUP BY CustomerID I get number of orders for each customer, but I can't retrieve both in the same table. Is there a way to do it in MySql?

Comment: Welcome to SO's code writing service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a MySQL 8+ way of doing this using a single pass query with analytic functions:

```
SELECT
    CustomerID,
    COUNT(*) AS num_orders,
    SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () AS total_num_orders
FROM Orders
GROUP BY
    CustomerID;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

You can try this -

```
select customerid, count(*) no_of_orders,
      (select count(*) from tablename) as total_no_of_orders
from tablename
group by customerid
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method by using window function:

```
   SELECT A.*, SUM(CUSTOMER_WISE_COUNT) OVER(ORDER BY CUSTOMERID ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) CUSTOMER_WISE_COUNT, CUSTOMERID FROM CUSTOMERS GROUP BY CUSTOMERID) A
```

;